# JOIN applies to only one table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to compile user project permissions from three tables. I came up with the below SQL code:

```
SELECT U.UserName,
       G.Name,
       (SELECT PROJ.Name
        FROM [test 2].dbo.Projects as PROJ
        WHERE PROJ.ProjectID = PERM.ProjectID) AS Project

FROM [test 2].dbo.tbl_Sp_Users AS U
JOIN [test 2].dbo.tbl_Sp_UserGrps AS G
ON U.DefGroupID=G.ID

JOIN [test 2].dbo.tbl_ss_Permission_Project AS PERM
ON U.ID = PERM.UserID

ORDER BY U.UserName ASC;
```

It seems to me that the way `JOIN` works is by picking one table and linking it to other tables. But what do I need to do if my main table doesn't have a direct link? I went around it by using a `SELECT` statement in my third column. Is that the best way to do it ?

Finally, another related simple question. How can I sort by the third column? It wouldn't let me `ORDER BY` **Project** which is the alias I have the column.

Comment: Do not get in the habit of using correlated subqueries, they can kill performance.

Comment: Was there an error with `order by Project`? I don't think there should be any problem with that.

Comment: @shawnt00 It works now. I think Intelisense took a while to catch up. But I did get an error before, not sure how it got resolved. How can I unambiguously refer that statement? Project is such a very generic name.

Comment: You can name it whatever you want: just change the `AS Project`. The `order by` clause refers to column by alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want a LEFT JOIN.
A left join does the same thing as an ordinary (INNER) join, but if if there is no match, it will still pull in the parent records.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  U.UserName
 ,G.Name
 ,proj.name
FROM
  [test 2].dbo.tbl_Sp_Users U
  inner JOIN [test 2].dbo.tbl_Sp_UserGrps G ON U.DefGroupID=G.ID
  inner JOIN [test 2].dbo.tbl_ss_Permission_Project PERM ON U.ID = PERM.UserID
  left join [test_2].dbo.Projects proj ON proj.projectid = PERM.projectid
ORDER BY
  U.UserName ASC;
```

Comment: The `JOIN` on [test 2].dbo.tbl_ss_Permission_Project needs to be a `LEFT JOIN` as well to show the NULL values. Just tried it out.

Comment: When you write that, you are basically saying "If there are no permissions set for this user at all, then I still want to return their row".  that makes sense.  My answer was emulating your original, which specifies an ordinary JOIN on that table.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT U.UserName,
       G.Name,
        PROJ.Name
FROM [test 2].dbo.tbl_Sp_Users AS U
JOIN [test 2].dbo.tbl_Sp_UserGrps AS G
    ON U.DefGroupID=G.ID
JOIN [test 2].dbo.tbl_ss_Permission_Project AS PERM
    ON U.ID = PERM.UserID
LEFT JOIN [test 2].dbo.Projects AS PROJ 
    ON  PROJ.ProjectID = PERM.ProjectID
ORDER BY U.UserName ASC;
```

Comment: His sub-query version will pull a NULL in cases where PROJ has no match.  An inner join won't.

Comment: I think i misunderstand `JOIN`. I was under the impression that it joins the table after the `FROM` statement with each of the `JOIN` statements afterwards. However, here your last `JOIN` uses tables unrelated to table `U` used in `FROM`.

Comment: @newdimension The link does not have to be "direct" as you put it. You can have a chain of joins.

Comment: @shawnt00 If the link isn't required, what value does the `FROM` statement add ? Can I put a `JOIN` right after the `FROM` without a table first ?

Comment: You're mistaken to refer to it as a "statement. The `from` clause basically lists out the tables that are referenced in the query. A `join` is part of the `from` and belongs with it. But no you can't really do that and I suppose you can think about it as "joining" the new table to the ones that have come before and you have to have a least one table. Don't worry too much about that though. It will make sense eventually.

Comment: You can also join to more than one table  such as JOIN TableC C on a.id =c.id and b.someotherid = c.someotherid